# Security threat with `home_url`?

Tags: security

In the docs of built-in function [home_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url),  it is said to be used with `esc_url`. Are there any security threats without using `home_url`?  Can someone spoof it with fake request?

Comment: Check those document i think it will be help you! https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/

Answer (score 1):

The codex states:

> Always use esc_url when sanitizing URLs (**in text nodes, attribute
>   nodes or anywhere else**). Rejects URLs that do not have one of the
>   provided whitelisted protocols (defaulting to http, https, ftp, ftps,
>   mailto, news, irc, gopher, nntp, feed, and telnet), eliminates invalid
>   characters, and removes dangerous characters. Replaces clean_url()
>   which was deprecated in 3.0.

Also the power behind this little helper function is the

```
get_option( 'home' );
```

This will be user input and you always don't trust user inputs. Also this helps output a valid markup.